# Should we exclude security response headers for static files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My application is a SpringBoot (along with embedded angular) application. For static files (images, js files etc), I have excluded them from Spring Security filters as:

```
class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**/*.js", "**/*.css", "/**/*.png");
   }
}
```

Since now static files will not be intercepted by Spring Security filters, security headers (such as **Strict-Transport-Security, X-XSS-Protection,Content-Security-Policy**) are not applied to these static files.

My question is should is it advisable to add such security headers for static resources (images, js files). If we don't apply these security headers on static files, is application vulnerable to security attack?

Comment: it is advisable to upgrade Spring Security as `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fully agree with @Toerktumlare, you must upgrade your security layer to newest version of `Spring Security` because there are many changes and also many deprecated and removed  like `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

More details about it you can find on :
[Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html),
[Spring-Security-Without-The-Websecurityconfigureradapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

About the question on `security for static resources`

*web.ignoring() means that Spring Security cannot provide any security headers or other protective measures on those endpoints.*

More details about this topic you can find on [10938](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10938), it was explain by **Josh Cummings** just check his comment on this ticket.

**UPDATE**

Some details about [Favor permitAll over ignoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#favor-permitall)

**UPDATE**

In my opinion these headers make sense for any page that is able to execute Javascript.

Comment: 1. I agree I should upgrade to latest version. But i guess my question would be relevant even for latest version.  May be my question is in general whether to bypass security headers for static files. 2. I had already mentioned in my original question that .."Since now static files will not be intercepted by Spring Security filters, security headers (such as Strict-Transport-Security, X-XSS-Protection,Content-Security-Policy) are not applied to these static files."..My question was "is it advisable to add such security headers for static resources (images, js files)."